# < SELECT > keyboard access issue

Tags: html, forms, select

I am in the process of converting an old client/server app to a <strike>web</strike> browser-based application, and have an issue with the standard HTML SELECT element.  Users of this app enter search term/operator pairs to construct a search on a large database (see sample markup below).

```
<input type="text" id="txtTerm1" />&nbsp;
<select id="selOp1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="or">Or</option>
    <option value="near">Near (any)</option>
    <option value="near2">Near (within 2 words)</option>
    <option value="near4">Near (within 4 words)</option>
    <option value="before">Before (any distance)</option>
    <option value="before2">Before (within 2 words)</option>
    <option value="before4">Before (within 4 words)</option>
</select>
```

A search term is entered into txtTerm1, and then TAB or ENTER is pressed to move to selOp1.  The users like to use the keyboard exclusively to choose an operator from selOp1.  When they quickly press "n", the select control iterates through the "near" options perfectly.  But if the user then decides they want to switch to "Or" and types "o,"  the control does not select the "Or" option.

Test:  Type n,n,n,n,n,o in rapid succession

It seems that if you type quickly and then change characters, the SELECT element groups the two characters together, "no" in this case, and does not find an OPTION with that text.  If I wait a few seconds after typing the n's and then press o, it works.  But this slows the users down and is confusing.  This behavior seems to be the same in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

The question:

Is there a way to force a SELECT to only use the first character of the OPTION text when trying to locate an OPTION with the keyboard?  Or does anyone have any other clever solutions?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *server/client to web application*. Aren't they same ;)

Comment: "`n,o` in rapid succession" does search for an `SELECT` entry that starts with `no…`. This is the intended behavior. You need a tiny pause between the keystrokes. You may also type `or` to select that entry. "But this slows the users down and is confusing." But on the other hand your use-case sounds a little bit constructed. If I see the select options (one may expand a `SELECT` using the `space`-key) I mostly know want I want to select before pressing any keys, as my brain is working faster than my fingers.

Comment: No, there is no way to influence that, the behavior is controlled by the OS. And there should be no _need_ to influence it in any way, since this is how `select` elements _always_ work, so the users should just get used to it. Other alternative might be an `input` field with an HTML5 `datalist`, maybe that behaves more like your users expect it.

Comment: I agree, there is an annoying amount of time you have to wait. What's also strange is that if you start cycling through `n`s, then type `o`: `n,n,o`, it does not select an entry that starts with `no`. Once you do type in a different letter, you cannot cycle the `n`s before waiting again. Very odd.

Comment: thanks for the input. I agree that there should be no need to influence this behavior.  But as we all know,  old user habits die hard, and they want the application to function EXACTLY like the old one.  maybe I can do something with an autocomplete extender or the HTML 5 input field, as CBroe suggested.